# how the android kernal controls the touch screen in android

Tags: android, kernel, touchscreen

how the android kernel controls the touch screen in android .

Actually i want the algorithm of android kernel which controls the android touch screen (display).

My main question how to change the display part without touching the display , by changing the android kernel according to my program.

PLease suggest the answer/links...

Comment: "My main question how to change the display part without touching the display" this is not clear... what you want to do exactly ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you really need to get into low level stuff you can use NDK